# Can I change default greeter in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: themes, login-screen

Is it possible to change default greeter in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Yes, you can, like you always could.

Comment: I hope I say the right thing. With greeter I mean the login screen. Is this the answer? https://websetnet.com/change-login-screen-background-ubuntu-17-10/

Comment: That answer is only for changing thew background picture, not the greeter (yes, the login screen) itself. That can be changed the same way as it always has been.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :-) CSS I can handle. But do I need to run xhost +local:  Not sure what that does. Isn't enough with sudo gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css , with a backup first?